# Java Selenium Inside Docker image(Selenium/standalone base image)

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, remotewebdriver

I use selenium/standalone-chrome base image
my Dockerfile is as below.

```
# Use the selenium/standalone-chrome base image
FROM  selenium/standalone-chrome:96.0.4664.45

USER root

# Install OpenJDK 11
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk

USER seluser

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Java source code
COPY src /app/src
COPY test /app/test

# Copy the Selenium WebDriver JAR file
COPY lib/selenium-server-4.1.2.jar /app/lib/selenium-server-4.1.2.jar

# Compile the Java code
RUN javac -cp ".:/app/lib/*" -d /app/classes /app/src/main/*.java /app/test/systemTests/*.java

# Set the entrypoint command to run the Java application
CMD ["java", "-cp", ".:/app/lib/*:/app/classes", "main.MainClass"]
```

//little example from the project

```
package main;
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your choice (1 for Instagram, 2 for Facebook):");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            InstagramTester instagramTester = new InstagramTester();
            instagramTester.testOpenClose();
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            FacebookTester facebookTester = new FacebookTester();
            facebookTester.testOpenClose();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please enter 1 or 2.");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}

package systemTests;

public class InstagramTester {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public InstagramTester() {
         ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
         chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
         chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
         URL remoteUrl;
         try {
             
             remoteUrl = new URL("http://chrome:4444/wd/hub"); 
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             System.err.println("Invalid Selenium Grid URL: " + e.getMessage());
             return;
         }

          this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteUrl, chromeOptions);
    }

    public void testOpenClose() {
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
        System.out.println("Page Title: " + driver.getTitle());
        closeBrowser();
    }

    public void closeBrowser() {
        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}

inside lib i got selenium-server-4.1.2.jar

   i first use :docker build -t basicscrapping .


after image  built 

 i enter :docker run -it  -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 basicscrapping   
   i enter 1 as input and after couple of minute
```

I got these errors :
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: chrome
.
.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: chrome
Any help is appreciated.(i dont use aby built tool like maven -gradle etc for project requirements)

Comment: The host `chrome` in `http://chrome:4444/wd/hub` cloud not be found. Can you check in the running docker container, that the host is reachable?

Comment: @Jelmen no not reachable .İ follow the documentation i am not sure about the reason not onyl chrome but also localhost dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access driver service using `http://chrome:4444/wd/hub` but actually in your example there is no any point where you assign a hostname to your container.

With `docker run` you can use `-h` flag, so that your command would be:

```
docker run -h chrome -it  -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 basicscrapping
```

**Or** in your code change `remoteUrl = new URL("http://chrome:4444/wd/hub");` to `remoteUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");`

Comment: Neither works unfortunately same error

Comment: Doesn't `localhost` work as well? It cannot produce the same error.

Comment: İ dont know the reason when i enter the localhost adress to my browser there is no connection still

Comment: Your browser local host is not the same as container's localhost. I was talking about `url` when you set up webdriver connectivity in your test. That code has to run in the container.

Comment: Yes so hardcoding is not a good idea then ? What should i do

Comment: if you are running the test code inside the same code as webdriver is deployed, it is perfectly fine to have `localhost`. You hardcode the host name anyway. Whether it is `chrome` or `localhost`.

Comment: i think that is the answer ,my code still dont work anyway but i think your answer will be helpful for the ones who encounter the same problem.

Comment: we can discuss your issue in more details in this chat-room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253867/java-selenium-inside-docker-imageselenium-standalone-base-image